# Trouble converting keras/tensorflow h5/json into tensorflow pb

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a network with keras (tensorflow backend) and saved the model as json and the weights as h5.  I'm now trying to convert this to a single tensorflow pb file and it's complaining about the name of the output node.

System Info:
Tensorflow 2.3.0
Keras 2.4.3
Cuda 10.1
Cudnn 7

The conversion script is very simple:

```
import json
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

json_file = "my-trained-model.json"
h5_file = "my-trained-model.h5"
Output_Path = "./trained_models/"
Frozen_pb_File = "my-trained-model.pb"

def freeze_session(session, keep_var_names=None, output_names=None, clear_devices=True):
   
    from tensorflow.python.framework.graph_util import convert_variables_to_constants
    graph = session.graph
    with graph.as_default():
        freeze_var_names = list(set(v.op.name for v in tf.compat.v1.global_variables()).difference(keep_var_names or []))
        output_names = output_names or []
        output_names += [v.op.name for v in tf.compat.v1.global_variables()]
        # Graph -> GraphDef ProtoBuf
        input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()
        if clear_devices:
            for node in input_graph_def.node:
                node.device = ""
        frozen_graph = convert_variables_to_constants(session, input_graph_def,
                                                      output_names, freeze_var_names)
        return frozen_graph


with open(json_file, 'r') as json_file:
    model = keras.models.model_from_json(json_file.read())
model.load_weights(h5_file)

model.summary()

# get output node names
OutputNames = [out.op.name for out in model.outputs]
print("\nOutput Names:\n", OutputNames)  # this prints "concatenate/concat" as the only output node name


# freeze the model
frozen_graph = freeze_session(tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session(), output_names=OutputNames)

# save the output files
# this is the .pb file (a binary file)
tf.io.write_graph(frozen_graph, Output_Path, Frozen_pb_File, as_text=False)
```

When I run this,

```
AssertionError: concatenate/concat is not in graph
```

So for some reason it's reading an output node name of "concatenate/concat".  The model summary is given below, and you can see that the output node is "concatenate"; however, even if I hard code the output node name to "concatenate", I get a similar assertion error:

```
AssertionError: concatenate is not in graph
```

Here's the keras model summary:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input (InputLayer)              [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, None, None, 1 448         input[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, None, None, 1 64          conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)         (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 1 2320        activation[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 1 64          conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, None, None, 1 0           activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 4640        max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 128         conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 3 0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 9248        activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 128         conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 3 0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 3 9248        activation_3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 3 128         conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, None, None, 3 0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
                                                                 activation_2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 3 0           add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, None, None, 3 0           activation_4[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_6[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
                                                                 activation_5[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 6 0           add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_8[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_9 (BatchNor (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_9[0][0]      
                                                                 activation_7[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)       (None, None, None, 6 0           add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, None, None, 6 0           activation_9[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 36928       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_11[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_10[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_12 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 6 0           add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_13 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 36928       activation_13[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 6 256         conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 6 0           batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_12[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_14 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 6 0           add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, None, None, 6 0           activation_14[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 73856       max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_15 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_15[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_16 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_16[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_17[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_5 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_15[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_17 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_17[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_18[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_18 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_18[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_18[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_19[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_6 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_19[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_17[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_19 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           add_6[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_19[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_20 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_20[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_20 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_20[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_20[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_21 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_21[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_7 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_21[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_19[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_21 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           add_7[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_21[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_22 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_22[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_22 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_22[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 1 147584      activation_22[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_23 (BatchNo (None, None, None, 1 512         conv2d_23[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_8 (Add)                     (None, None, None, 1 0           batch_normalization_23[0][0]     
                                                                 activation_21[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_23 (Activation)      (None, None, None, 1 0           add_8[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 2 2306        activation_23[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)              (None, None, None, 6 6918        activation_23[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, None, None, 8 0           conv2d_24[0][0]                  
                                                                 conv2d_25[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,648,184
Trainable params: 1,644,344
Non-trainable params: 3,840
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I must be overlooking something simple, but have stared at it so long, I can no longer see the forest for the trees.  :-(

Thanks for any advice.  I'll gladly share the json/h5 to anyone interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was all caused by trying to freeze a tensorflow 2.3 model.  Apparently, Tensorflow 2.0+ has deprecated the "frozen" concept and moved on to the "saved model" concept.  Once discovering this, I was able to immediately save the h5/json to a saved model pb.

I'm still not sure if this format is optimized for inference, so I'll be doing some follow up with that, but since my question was about the error I was seeing, I thought I would post what was causing the problem.

For reference, here's my python script for converting from the keras h5/json files to the Tensorflow saved model format.

```
import os
from keras.models import model_from_json
import tensorflow as tf
import genericpath
from genericpath import *

def splitext(p):
    p = os.fspath(p)
    if isinstance(p, bytes):
        sep = b'/'
        extsep = b'.'
    else:
        sep = '/'
        extsep = '.'
    return genericpath._splitext(p, sep, None, extsep)

def load_model(path,custom_objects={},verbose=0):
    from keras.models import model_from_json

    path = splitext(path)[0]
    with open('%s.json' % path,'r') as json_file:
        model_json = json_file.read()
    model = model_from_json(model_json, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    model.load_weights('%s.h5' % path)
    # if verbose: print 'Loaded from %s' % path
    return model


json_file = "model.json"  # the h5 file should be "model.h5"

model = load_model(json_file) # load the json/h5 pair
model.save('my_saved_model') # this is a directory name to store the saved model
```